# Animations in apps

Tags: c#, windows, animation

I'm not familiar with app development so I want to gain a better understanding on how animations are implemented in apps as I have different ideas.

I have designed 4 images using Adobe Illustrator, 3 of the images are planets and 1 image is a rocket. In my app I would like the rocket to randomly move to a planet when clicking a button, the ideas I have to implement this are:

1. Programatically move the rocket pixel by pixel towards the randomly selected planet

Or

2. Create 3 different animations of the rocket moving to each planet and when the random planet has been selected play the correct rocket animation.

Which one is the best approach for what I am trying to achieve? If you have better please can you share as I do not know how to go about doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a trade off between download size / performance / versatility / maintainability / implementation time.

1. Will use more processor, result in a smaller program size, be more versatile (you could allow the user to control the rocket and detect when they arrive at a target planet)
2. Will use less processor, be simpler to implement, result in a larger program size. You'd need to remake the animations in the case of adding a new planet, doesn't scale well (What happens when you have 20 planets? with different screen resolutions?)

Comment: True, this is where i'm now stuck, it will be a very long and hard process with the 2nd idea as i'd have to make sure everything is the correct size for the animation to work perfectly. Do you think their is any better ideas?

Comment: The easiest way will _usually_ be to use a framework, like Unity or even just WPF (depends on platforms/targets). In which case you'd go with the first method and IMHO it should be fairly trivial

Comment: Ouch! Do you have an idea of the most common approach developers take with applications?

Comment: without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve I can't really offer more advice. Using a magic 8 ball I'd guess you want option 1 with something like WPF/Silverlight to process rotations / movements with minimum fuss.